# Subscripts (or other math formula) in ggplot2 legend factor labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, legend, subscript

I tried to add subscripts to my ggplot2 geom_point colour legend by using `scale_colour_discrete`. Similar problems popped up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284544/expressions-from-data-frame-to-ggplot2-legend)

```
p <- ggplot(myData, aes(myFeature1,myFeature2))
p <- p + geom_point(aes(colour = myFeature3)) + facet_grid(n ~ cond)
p <- p + scale_colour_discrete(breaks = levels(myData$myFeature3), labels = c(expression(myFeature3[1]),expression(myFeature3[2]))
```

However, the following error occurs:
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  cannot coerce type 'symbol' to vector of type 'double'

This error does NOT occur, without in the `labels` definition `expression`. It DOES occur whatever is inside the `expression`.

Any ideas on the subject? Does `scale_colour_discrete` just not work with `expression`? Is there another way to get subscripts into those legend factor names?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the `diamonds` data set where the labels for the diamond cut are replaced by Cut_1, ..., Cut_5.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut)) + 
  facet_grid(color ~ clarity) + 
  scale_colour_discrete(breaks = levels(diamonds$cut), 
                        labels = c(expression(Cut[1]),
                                   expression(Cut[2]),
                                   expression(Cut[3]),
                                   expression(Cut[4]),
                                   expression(Cut[5])))
```

If this is not helping you find a solution to your problem can you provide a reproducible example for others to trouble shoot?

Answer (score 1):

Can't replicate this without your data. Trying something similar with the 'diamonds' data as described in help(scale_colour_discrete):

```
d + scale_colour_discrete(breaks=levels(diamonds$clarity),labels=rep(expression(a^2),8))
```

works, labelling all levels with a-squared in math notation.

```
d + scale_colour_discrete(breaks=levels(diamonds$clarity),labels=rep(expression(clarity[1]),8))
```

works, labelling with clarity subscript 1 in all levels.